# How spring rest recognizes a new session?

Tags: java, spring, rest, session

I have a problem to understand how spring rest recognizes a new session. Let's assume we have simple session bean defined like that:

```
@SessionScope
public class Counter {

  private int counter;

  public int inc() {
    return counter++;
  }
}
```

We have also a simple rest controller that provides get method that calls `inc()` method of the Counter and returns its current value.
I was expecting that every single request (made in postman) will result in getting value 1 since there is no way to recognize the session. For instance there is no JSESSION_ID cookie like it was in traditional servlet-based app. What I actually get is increased value of the counter and it does not matter if I make request in postman, web-browser or curl. Even using browser in private mode still refers to the same instance of the bean.
The question is how spring recognizes new sessions and how I can simulate different sessions in my "test" envinronment.

Comment: `@SessionScope` means one instance "per session", so this counter won't increment because when Spring creates a new session a new instance of `Counter` is created too.

Comment: And the problem is that it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found - bean was missing `@Component` annotation. With that JSESSION_ID cookie is created and obviously this is the way spring recognizes session.